# Reloading the frontend on new release with SwUpdate and Service Worker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-service-worker

I want update my frontend with a reload when a new version is released.

What i'm doing wrong?

*update.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UpdateService {

  constructor(private updates: SwUpdate) {
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      interval(1000 * 60).subscribe(() => updates.checkForUpdate().then());
    }
  }

  public checkForUpdates(): void {
    this.updates.available.subscribe(() => this.promptUser());
  }

  private promptUser(): void {
    this.updates.activateUpdate().then(() => {
      document.location.reload();
    });
  }
}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UpdateService } from './core/services/update/update.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ac-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private updateService: UpdateService) {
    this.updateService.checkForUpdates();
  }
}
```

*ngsw-config.json*

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: currently facing the same issue, did you find a solution?